# Unexpected Identifier in Chrome's console

Tags: javascript

I tested this javascript in Chrome's console and it returned  an error about unexpected identifier. I thought i had the syntax right, but obviously its not. 
Can you please help me?

Thanks

```js
function printQuote(){ 
    var theRandomQuote = getRandomQuote();
    var message = "<p class="quote">quotes.quote</p>";
    message += "<p class="source">quotes.source";
    message += "<span class="citation">quotes.citation</span></p>";
    print(message);
}
```

Comment: Look at your quote usage in lines like `var message = "<p class="quote">quotes.quote</p>";` Voting to close due to typos. You should spend a little time learning basic debugging techniques.

Comment: Use different " and ' to distinguish strings and "strings in strings". Also [print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) is not what you think it is (it prints the page)

Comment: [MDN - String - JavaScript - Escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation)

Answer (score 0):

Replace inner doublequotes with singlequotes

```js
function printQuote(){ 
    var theRandomQuote = getRandomQuote();
    var message = "<p class='quote'>quotes.quote</p>";
    message += "<p class='source'>quotes.source";
    message += "<span class='citation'>quotes.citation</span></p>";
    print(message);
}
```

Comment: Questions caused by typos are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be flagged / closed, not answered

Comment: I'll remember that.

Answer (score 0):

You might try escaping the double quotes:

```
function printQuote(){ 
    var theRandomQuote = getRandomQuote();
    var message = "<p class=\"quote\">quotes.quote</p>";
    message += "<p class=\"source\">quotes.source";
    message += "<span class=\"citation\">quotes.citation</span></p>";
    print(message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Questions caused by typos are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be flagged / closed, not answered